# Firebase pubsub function schedule invalid schedule or timezone

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

When I try to deploy my newly created Firebase PubSub function, I get the error `Error: Failed to create scheduler job projects/workouts-uat/locations/europe-west1/jobs/firebase-schedule-dailyTasks-eur3: HTTP Error: 400, Schedule or time zone is invalid.`

My function is declared as follows:

```
exports.dailyTasks = functions
  .region('europe-west2')
  .pubsub
  .schedule('every 24 hours 00:00')
  .timeZone('Africa/Johannesburg')
  .onRun(...);
```

From my research I found that that the region used should be the same as the region found in your project settings, which in my case is `eur3 (europe-west)`. All my existing `onCall` functions use `europe-west2` which is why I tried to go with that first, but after finding my project settings region I updated to `.region('eur3')` and `.region('europe-west')`, but the error persists. So how do I successfully deploy this function?

Another hint I came across while googling the error was that a "Google App Engine (GAE) app" has to be created for pubsub functions to work, but I'm assuming that happens automatically on function deploy, right? Otherwise how does one create that? I have zero experience with GCP.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I finally figured this out. It had nothing to do with the `.timeZone()`, as I originally thought - it was an error with the `.schedule()`. And yes, I just saw that the error message does include the possibility that it could be the "**Schedule** or time zone", but for some reason I thought it was referring to the function as a whole and not the `.schedule()` call.

In any case, once I updated my `every 24 hours 00:00` to `every day 00:00`, it all of a sudden deployed just fine. For clarity, this is what my working function signature now looks like:

```
exports.dailyTasks = functions
.region('europe-west2')
.pubsub
.schedule('every day 00:00')
.timeZone('Africa/Johannesburg')
```

As it turns out, `.region()` also had nothing to do with it, and `europe-west2` works just fine.

I'd like to thank the author of [this](https://codeburst.io/cron-cloud-functions-for-firebase-724728b1683a) article, because he linked an example project that also calls a pubsub function every day at midnight, and without said article, I'd have never found the answer.

Comment: Hi, is it possible to see the logs of the dialyTasks function in your emulator log?

Answer (score 0):

I was having significant issues getting it to accept a schedule. I ended up finding [this list](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/configuring/cron-job-schedules?&_ga=2.54747565.-740595395.1703019480#sample_schedules) of valid schedules (copied below)

| Schedule | Cron Job Format | Explanation |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Every minute | `* * * * *` | Runs on the minute. For example, 9:00 AM, 9:01 AM, :02 AM, and so on. |
| Every hour | `0 * * * *` | Runs on the hour. For example, 9:00 AM, 10:00 AM, 11:00 AM, and so on. |
| Every day | `0 0 * * *` | Runs at 12:00 AM (00:00 in 24-hour format) every day. |
| Every weekday | `0 0 * * 1-5` | Runs at 12:00 AM (00:00 in 24-hour format) on Mondays, Tuesdays, Wednesdays, Thursdays, and Fridays. |
| Every week | `0 0 * * 0` | Runs on Sundays at 12:00 AM (00:00 in 24-hour format). |
| Every month | `0 0 1 * *` | Runs at 12:00 AM (00:00 in 24-hour format) on the first day of the month. |
| Every quarter | `0 0 1 1,4,7,10 *` | Runs at 12:00 AM (00:00 in 24-hour format) on the first day of the quarter: January 1st, April 1st, July 1st, and October 1st. |
| Every year | `0 0 1 1 *` | Runs at 12:00 AM (00:00 in 24-hour format) on the first day of the first month of the year (January 1st). |